# Installing OpenSSL on CentOS vagrant box gives 404 error

Tags: networking, openssl, centos, vagrant

I'm running a CentOS 6 vagrant virtual machine under VMWare Fusion. The machine is working well. I need to test LDAP over SSL which requires me to install OpenSSL, so I ran `sudo yum install openssl` and I get the following errors:

```
http://mirror5.layerjet.com/remi/enterprise/6/remi/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [
Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 - "Failed to connect to 2a01:4f8:11a:b1f::1: Network is
 unreachable"
Trying other mirror.

http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/extras/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYC
URL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.

Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: repoforg
eextras. Please verify its path and try again
```

Googling this error led me to try and clear the metadata cache with `sudo yum clean metadata` and `sudo yum clean all`, both of which evidently work but when I try and install OpenSSL I get the same errors.

Comment: can you run `netstat -nr` on your VM ?

Comment: Sure, I get this:
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
172.16.44.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         172.16.44.2     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0

Comment: `ping6 2a01:4f8:11a:b1f::1` results in `ping6: UDP connect: No route to host` for me. I would disable IPv6, and go back to IPv4.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Fair enough, I'll ask this in Super User.